# Jersey ExceptionMapper issue

Tags: jersey

When I try to caught exceptions which like ConstraintViolationException, JsonMappingException and etc according to by ExceptionMapper< Exception>, but it does not work. It just worked by ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> or ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> At present, in my project, there had multi handler to process the various exception.

Anybody can help me to clarify the problem? Is there have any solutions for my problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: keep your ExceptionMapper class under resource package class, then try it